# On maven how do I ignore an expression (EL) inside a resource file? ${user.home}

Tags: java, maven

I have this pom.xml:

```
<project>
...
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
</project>
```

Inside "src/main/resources/", I have this file log4j.xml.

```
...
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
  <param name="File" value="${user.home}/myApp/myLog.log"/>
  <param name="Append" value="true"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value="_yyyy-MM'.log'"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c:%L] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
...
```

My issue is when I do $ mvn clean install, the ${user.home} gets translated to

```
<param name="File" value="C:\\Users\\myUser/myApp/myLog.log"/>
```

So how can I ignore this case ${user.home} to stay on target directory with the same ${user.home}, because log4j needs to know user directory of any machine that runs my app.

Note: I also want to clarify, that I have more resource files that has to be filtered.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this solution, to use escapeString on maven-resources-plugin, here is the code snippet:

```
<project>
...
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <escapeString>\</escapeString>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
</plugins>
...
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
</project>
```

and on log4j configuration file, need to add "\", before the property.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender">
  <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler"/>
  <param name="File" value="\${user.home}/myApp/myLog.log"/>
  <param name="Append" value="true"/>
  <param name="Threshold" value="INFO"/>
  <param name="DatePattern" value="_yyyy-MM'.log'"/>
  <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d %-5p [%c:%L] %m%n"/>
  </layout>
</appender>
```

See documentation: [Escape Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/escape-filtering.html)

I hope someone find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add an `<excludes>` tag to your pom.xml so that this file is not copied when filtering is true and add a second resource block to copy just this file without filtering

```
<project>
...
<build>
    ...
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>log4j.xml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>log4j.xml</exclude>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that excludes log4j.xml file from being copied to my target directory.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  What you need I'd two resource blocks, for src/main/resources. In the first block have filtering true and exclude log4j.xml and in the second block have filtering false and include log4j.xml